# Rough idle, Car hesitation (jolting sensation), Lack of Power, No check engine light

Tags: maintenance, rough-idle, shaking

I have a 2006 honda fit and i am experiencing some Rough idle, Car hesitation (jolting sensation), Lack of Power in my car sprecially when the AC is on. And whenever i put the car on drive the rpm just goes up and down accompanied with the rough shaking. I already did some small tune up thinking it would solve the problem but it didnt and i dont want to spend money more than what i really need to. So can you honorable dudes help me narrow down whats causing the problem? it would be a very big help. btw my car knowledge is close to zero and i only have the internet to rely on so....

Edit:
Car stalls on idle speeds

What i did so far:
replaced all 8 spark plugs, replaced the vavle cover gasket

Answer (score 1):

try to check the internal of the engine because you tell that the idle rpm is rough. Usually because the engine oil is too dirty I mean many carbon deposit on your internal engine. Many issues that car owner not changing the oil regularly causing the internal component not properly working. then after that try to check and clean the intake manifold, throttle body, fuel line and all the sensors.

hope this can help!